# Getting the max value using regex in Mysql

Tags: mysql, max

I have a column `invoice_id` in table `invoices`. The invoice_id format is

> INV-2-43-**001**-01
>   INV-2-43-**002**-01
>   INV-2-43-**002**-02

And i want to get the highest value in bold columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the format you can get it by two ways,I have used [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the number and one approach is use the limit with order by

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Inv,'-',-2),'-',1) inv
FROM Table1
ORDER BY inv DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And other is to use the MAX() function

```
select 
MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Inv,'-',-2),'-',1)) inv
FROM Table1
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a4ef/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also in this way:

```
SELECT
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Inv),4, 3))
FROM Table1
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a4ef/10)**